# Array isn't getting the right range of data

Tags: vb.net, cad

I want to store data in an array using an 4th degree equation.  But i only want points from a certain range.
My range needs to be `x=0,2*Q` to `x=1,5*Q`, so the loop needs to start at `x=0,2*Q` and ends when `x=1,5*Q`. `Q` is a variable read from a text file, and is for example 9. 
I use this data to draw curves in a 3D Cad program called Solid Edge. 
The problem is, the data doesn't store how i wnat it. It does start from were i want it but doesnt end at the point i want it. The program stops when `y` is that number. But i only want that to happen with `x`.

My solid edge version is ST2, and this console application needs to work on ST5.
In solid Edge i use the calculated array to make curves with:

```
Bsplinecurve2d = BsplineCurves2d.AddByPoints(order, ArraySize, dataArray)
```

I'm using visual basic 2003, and i know using a newer version is better. But i can't. I'm an intern at a engineering office and they only had this copie of visual basic.
Here is the part of my code what isn't doing what i want:

```
    dim x as double
        dim y as double
dim i as double
    Dim listofdata As New ArrayList
         For i = 0.2 To 1.5 Step 0.1
                    x = (i * Q)
                    y = (((x ^ 4) * A) + ((x ^ 3) * B) + ((x ^ 2) * C) + (x * D) + E)
                    listofdata.Add(x)
                    listofdata.Add(y)
                Next
                Dim dataArray() As Double
                dataArray = DirectCast(listofdata.ToArray(GetType(Double)), Double())
```

Comment: Where is the text file in your code?

Comment: This is just a part of my code, to post my whole code it will a bit much. The text file gets read by a streamreader that reads the data in substrings.

Comment: As things stand, I don't quite understand what you are asking.

Comment: It wasnt very clear indeed. I've changed it a bit now,  i hope it's better now. If not i will make it better next week, because i don't got much time at the moment.

Comment: I don't quite follow neither. i is your counter here and will stop at 1.5. x doesn't do anything to stopping, and if Q <> 1 then x will never end at 1.5. Could you elaborate a little more? You want the loop to break when result of iQ  =1.5?

Comment: Ah okay thank you i will, but that will be this weekend or monday.

Comment: Are you sure you want `x` and `y` in your list sequentially? like `x1`,`y1`,`x2`,`y2`,`..` and not in some kind of structure, or separate arrays? Just wondering.

Comment: I think you need to show as what `SolidEdge` is expecting in `dataArray` before we can comment on the code.

Comment: What `ST` version are you targeting? It makes a difference in which version of `vb.net` is supported.

Comment: I wnat my loop to stop when x=1,5Q, and i wnat to store is like x1,y1,x2,y2 because thats tghe order i need for solid edge to read the array. And i am making this with ST2 and it also needs to work on ST5.

Comment: Q is read from a text file because, there ar muliple rows in the file with different data in it to make a curve. AL the lines that are in the text file should be read and from al of them  needs to make a curve.

Answer (score 0):

OK i figured it out. My counter stopped before x=1.5*Q somehow.
But when i made it x=1.6*Q the array stops at the right and. 
Not sure why i had to that, but it workd now.